# Windows Service end of starting process notification (2003,2008)

Tags: c++, windows-services, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I have a service (C++) that during its startup might sleep for 10 minutes (error case). 
in 2003 - it worked fine, when I migrated the code to 2008 product, Windows Services notify me that the service could not start (my application still alive - but from windows perspective after 1 minute it claims there is a problem..)

-> Though the code was migrated to newer version no change in code flow 
-> there is only one thread that starts everything.
-> I can't start the application if this error occurs (I must sleep).
-> Is there any change in 2008 behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are changes in how session-ids are maintained. The interactive logged-in user would get session-id starting with 1 (In Windows 7/2008), which used to be 0 for previous versions of Windows.

Along with that there are restrictions on how services can interact with the desktop. If service creates/shows windows, it will NOT be rendered to session that belongs to current user, but it would be shown via session-id 0' desktop.

You may check [this discussion](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-security/41335-any-reason-session-id-1-instead-0-vista.html)